# Morris.js number and date format

Tags: morris.js

I'm using [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) line charts. I'd like to display dates as **dd/mm/YYYY** instead of **YYYY-mm-dd**. Is it possible? I'm also using time such as **01.00.56**, **00.55.44** etc. but this format is not recognized. How can I display time of the format (minutes.seconds.milliseconds)? Any help would be appreciated.

This is my data

```
var data = [
  { y: '20-05-2014', a: 01.00.45},
  { y: '17-06-2015', a: 00.56.20}
],
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try the function *dateFormat*.

From the help:

> A function that accepts millisecond timestamps and formats them for
>   display as chart labels.  default: function (x) { return new
>   Date(x).toString(); }